Stability of Hamiltonian system on degenerate critical point.
I'm trying to find information on the stability of the following ODE:
$$ x'' = x^4-x^2.$$
We know that it has a Hamiltonian $H(x,y) = \dfrac{y^2}{2} - (\dfrac{x^5}{5} - \dfrac{x^3}{3})$. The orbits are given by the equation
$$ y(x) = \pm \sqrt{\alpha(3x^5 - 5x^3 - \beta)}$$

for constants $\alpha = 2/15$ and $15\beta = H(x,y)$. Now, we know that $3x^5 - 5x^3 - \beta$ is positive when the graph of $P(x) = 3x^5 - 5x^3$ is above the line $y=\beta$. Looking at the graph we see that the domain of definition is disconnected when the line is in between the local extrema of $P(x)$ and only becomes connected when the line goes above or below the local extrema of $P(x)$. From this information, we can conclude that the critical points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ obviously have to be a centre and a saddle point. However, we can't get any information on the critical point at $(0,0)$. Looking at the direction field

We kind of expect it to be a centre, but I really don´t know how to prove this. Geometrical reasoning aside, it easy to check that the Hessian has positive eigenvalues at $(-1,0)$ and that the Jacobian has a positive and a negative eigenvalue at $(1,0)$ and thus these points are a centre and a saddle point, but what do I do at zero?

The Jacobian and Hessian of $H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}2-\frac{x^5}5+\frac{x^3}3$ are
$$
\nabla H=\pmatrix{-x^4+x^2\\y}\,,\quad \nabla^2H=\pmatrix{-4x^3+2x&0\\0&1}\,. 
$$
The Jacobian has no eigenvalues as you wrote but zeroes at $(-1,0),(0,0),(+1,0)\,.$ At those points the Hessian is
$$
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}\,,\quad \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\,,\quad \pmatrix{-2 & 0\\ 0&1}\,.
$$
At $(\mp1,0)$ the situation is pretty clear (relative minimum, resp. saddle point).

At $(0,0)$ the curve $x\mapsto H(x,0)$ neither has a minimum nor a maximum.

With this defintion that point is therefore a saddle point.


